# Windows universal URI format exception

Tags: exception, uri, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm working on a windows universal app. I want to show the user an image. The image is located in a subfolder within my assets folder, in both the phone and the windows folder.

I'm trying to put the image in a variable in a class that is in the shared folder. I am continously getting uri exceptions.

My code looks like this:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("/Assets/Image/avatar_anonymous.png");
chat_profilepicture_Bitmap = new BitmapImage(uri);
```

I've tried different urls, with and without capitals, the entire path "C://blablabla", and many more. Nothing seems to be working. I have also tried: pack://application:,,,/ which was suggested by multiple stackoverflow threads. But no luck there.

I'm thinking the problem lies in the image being in another project, is there a way to get around this? Or if this isn't the problem, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Uri uri = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Image/avatar_anonymous.png");

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
Uri uri = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Image/avatar_anonymous.png");
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I've wasted hours on this.

Answer (score 3):

In Windows Universal App, You can use Image Resource with **ms-appx** or **ms-appdata**.

- **ms-appx**  means using resource in App Package
- **ms-appdata** menas using resource in floder of local, temp or roam.

So the uri can be written like this:

```
new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Image/avatar_anonymous.png", UriKind.Absolute);
```

or

```
new Uri("ms-appdata:///LocalFolderName/demo.png", UriKind.Absolute);
```